# \DTLifinlist crashes when used with \dtlexpandnewvalue & the character 'é'

Tags: datatool

The following code gives the error

> ! You can't use `macro parameter character #' in horizontal mode.
>   \DTLifinlist ...4->\def \@dtl@doifinlist ##1,#1,##
>                                                     2\end@dtl@doifinlist {\def... l.18 }

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{datatool}

\begin{document}

\DTLnewdb{dtOne}%
\dtlexpandnewvalue
\DTLnewrow{dtOne}%
\DTLnewdbentry{dtOne}{Place}{Marché}%

\DTLforeach*{dtOne}%
{\Place=Place}%
{%
    \expandafter\DTLifinlist\expandafter{\Place}{Car,Man,Ferry}%
    {\Place: Found!\\}%
    {\Place: Not found!\\}%
}

\end{document}
```

If I `%\dtlexpandnewvalue` or if I change the db entry to `\DTLnewdbentry{dtOne}{Place}{Marche}%` ('**é**' changed in '**e**'), the error goes away.

Is there a way to use `\DTLifinlist` with `\dtlexpandnewvalue` and accented characters?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might protect the entry against expansion and then compare the entries as strings.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{datatool}

\newcommand{\DTLstringifinlist}[4]{%
  \begingroup\edef\x{\endgroup
    \noexpand\DTLifinlist{\detokenize\expandafter{#1}}{\detokenize{#2}}%
  }\x{#3}{#4}%
}
\newcommand{\DTLnewdbprotectedentry}[3]{%
  \DTLnewdbentry{#1}{#2}{\unexpanded{#3}}%
}

\begin{document}

\DTLnewdb{dtOne}
\dtlexpandnewvalue
\DTLnewrow{dtOne}
\DTLnewdbprotectedentry{dtOne}{Place}{Marché}

\DTLforeach*{dtOne}
  {\Place=Place}%
  {%
    \DTLstringifinlist{\Place}{Car,Man,Ferry}%
    {\Place: Found!}%
    {\Place: Not found!}%
  }

\DTLforeach*{dtOne}
  {\Place=Place}%
  {%
    \DTLstringifinlist{\Place}{Car,Man,Ferry,Marché}%
    {\Place: Found!}%
    {\Place: Not found!}%
  }

\DTLforeach{dtOne}{\Place=Place}{\Place}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Works with `pdflatex`, `xelatex` and `lualatex`.

Answer (score 2):

Yes! Just use XeLaTeX to compile your code and no errors will be generated!

Alternatively, if you insist on using pdfLaTeX, you can replace `Marché` with `March\'e`, and no errors will be generated.

---

I shall quote from the [`datatool` documentation](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/datatool/datatool-user.pdf):

> **Page 84**: As from version 2.24, the predefined handlers now have limited support for UTF-8 characters. *This is still experimental.*

and

> **Page 85**: With regular (pdf)LaTeX (as opposed to XeLaTeX) each UTF-8 character is actually treated as two tokens that represent the first and second octet of the UTF-8 character. This means that it’s not possible for TeX to obtain a character code using the usual backtick method…

Comment: LuaLatex would also be an option.

Comment: Indeed, March\'e solves the problem. So, UTF-8 seems to dislike `\DTLifinlist` only ... as I have no problem with the other Datatool commands. Rem: the note of page 84 is about the sorting handlers.

Comment: @JosephMarie If you look at the example of `\DTLnewdbentry` on page 46 of the documentation, you will find that the author intentionally used `Z\"oe` instead of `Zöe`. My point is that UTF-8 is not very-well supported (it could be a bug of the package).